# Rails transaction rollback does not happen if after_create fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my `User` model I have a after_created callback as

```
after_create :count_files
def count_files
  errors[:base] << "error working"
  errors.add(:base, "error working")        
  return false
end
```

As you can see, I am always adding base errors and returning false always, but still user is created. I think, if `after_create` returns false then automatic rollback happens instead of saving data in database. But for my case, data is always saving in database and transaction rollback doesn't happen. Why is that? how can I prevent user from being created if my `after_create` fails?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you running?

Comment: The keyword here is `after`. Rails docs and guides has all this explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`after_create` means the `INSERT` has already happened: the object is already created.

Instead of `after_create` you can add custom validation, like:

```
validate :count_files

private

def count_files
   count = counting_hear
   errors.add(:base, "error working")  if count < 10
end
```

**EDITED**

If you want to use callbacks (`after_create`), raise an exception instead of returning false:

```
after_create :count_files

def count_files
  errors[:base] << "error working"
  errors.add(:base, "error working")        
  raise MySuperCustomExeption
end
```

Comment: I thought that `after_commit` meant that the transaction already closed. My understanding is that the transaction should still be open at this point.

Comment: According to the guides, you can still roll back the transaction by raising `ActiveRecord::Rollback` in an `after_` callback. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution Your solution of creating the validation is what I'd recommend too, but your explanation in the answer is not 100% accurate.

Comment: try, if you wanna use `after_create`, change `return false` to `raise Exeption`

Comment: Please update the answer with raise exception. Thats the solution I am looking for.

Comment: answer was changed

Answer (score 0):

Before Rails 5, returning false from any before_ callback in ActiveModel or ActiveModel::Validations, ActiveRecord and ActiveSupport resulted in halting of callback chain.